# Finding Marshallian Demand without Lagrange?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics, utility

I need to find Marshallian demand for goods x and y (in terms of $P_x, P_y,$ and $I$) with the following utility function: $$U(x,y) = x + 10y - y^2$$ and general budget constraint $$I = P_xx + P_yy$$ I've already attempted to use the Lagrangian method to find both functions. For $x^m$ I get $$x^m = I/P_x - 10P_y/P_x + P_y^2/P_x^2$$ by utilizing the relationship between the MRS and the price ratio: $$\frac{MU_x}{MU_y} = \frac{1}{(10-2y)} = \frac{P_x}{P_y}$$ which gives me
$$y = \frac{10P_x-P_y}{2P_x}$$ which can then be substituted into the budget constraint to yield the above $x^m$, after some algrebra.

However, and this is the main issue, since $MU_x = 1$, I have hit a roadblock in attempting to solve for $x$ from the MRS/price ratio, so as to substitute it into the budget function to find $y^m$ like I normally would with the Lagrangian method. Is there another method of finding Marshallian demand? Or am I simply not applying the Lagrangian method correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You  solved the equation incorrectly.

$$\frac{1}{(10-2y)} = \frac{P_x}{P_y}$$

Flipping numerators and denominators.

$$10-2y = \frac{P_y}{P_x}$$

$$10-\frac{P_y}{P_x} = 2y$$

$$y=5-\frac{P_y}{2P_x}$$

Then $$x=\frac{I-P_y\cdot y}{P_x}=\frac{I}{P_x}-\frac{P_y}{P_x}\cdot y$$

Inserting the expression of $y$

$$x=\frac{I}{P_x}-\frac{P_y}{P_x}\cdot \left(5-\frac{P_y}{2P_x}\right)$$

$$x=\frac{I}{P_x}-\frac{5P_y}{P_x}+\frac{P_y^2}{2P_x^2}$$

Comment: Okay, so that solves for the marshallian demand for good x. The main problem still stands, that I'm unable to find the demand for good y, because I can't use the same method there. It seems that there's no way to manipulate the MRS = price ratio relationship to give me a value for which I can substitute x. The last equation in your answer, when substituted into the budget constraint, will simply yield the budget constraint again.

Comment: @user3791066 The MRS=price ration is not enough to find $x$. You also have to differentiate the lagrange function w.r.t the $\lambda$ (multiplier). This is just the constraint: Then set it equal to zero: $I-P_x\cdot x-P_y\cdot y=0$. That´s the way it goes.

Comment: *The last equation in your answer, when substituted into the budget constraint, will simply yield the budget constraint again* Not really. You´ll get the expression for $x$ in terms of $I, P_x $ and $P_y$.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the problem I'm encountering. Even if I solve out the $I - P_xx - P_yy = 0$ for $x$, and then substitute that as I did with the $y$ that was obtained from the MRS = Price Ratio, it just yields $I = I$ or some other equivalent expression. Normally, the way to utilize the budget constraint (the first order condition for which is indeed obtained from the $\lambda$ multiplier), would be to use the $x$ and $y$ values found from the MRS/PR relationship and substitute them in. As stated in the question, the problem is that there is no $x$ value to be obtained from the MRS/PR.

Comment: I will make an edit to show how y looks like. Please note my previous comment as well.

Comment: _Not really. You´ll get the expression for x in terms of I,Px and Py._ Respectfully, yes it will. Substituting $x = \frac{I}{P_x} - \frac{P_y}{P_x}y$ into $I = P_xx +P_yy$ yields $I = I$ after simplification.

Comment: @user3791066 It is $x = \frac{I}{P_x} - \frac{P_y}{P_x}\color{blue}y$. Then insert the the expression for y.

Comment: Okay, seeing your most recent edit, I understand what you're saying. The difference is that you said originally that I would need to substitute the rearranged budget constraint back into the budget constraint, and that is where the confusion came for me. But, I didn't think to substitute in the $y$ from the MRS/PR before putting it back into the budget constraint! So that makes sense. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @user3791066 It pleases me, that it is all clear now. And mark the answer as accepted, thanks..  You´re welcome.